# RPi Zero 2 W monitor image lost during boot

Tags: hdmi, power-supply, screen, pi-zero-w-2

**TLDR: RPi Zero 2W outputs image only for a few seconds then stops**

My brand new Zero 2W is having issues with the monitor image.

During boot I can see the init messages going by and at some point during boot the image goes black and the monitor says no input signal. I then reboot and get the same result: Some messages from init, then stops.
This happens every time, always at the same point during the boot, sightly after init sets the hostname.

I have made many attempts to fully boot this but it never worked. This is what I've attempted in different combinations:

- 2 different OS images: Raspbian desktop image (Oct 30 release) and Raspbian lite image (Oct 30 release)
- 2 different chargers of 5V 2.4A (both of the same exact model)
- Another charger (this one 5V 1.5A)
- Another monitor and hdmi cable
- Fiddling with hdmi_* parameters in config.txt including the hdmi_safe=1 alone or with hdmi_group=2,hdmi_mode=82 (1080p)

The result is always the same, it appears slightly after init sets the hostname, the RPi stops sending hdmi signal. It never reaches the login prompt.

For the sake of it I've replaced the pi zero 2W with an older pi zero 1 (non W) with the 1.5A charger referenced above, using the same SD card and same monitor and had no issue getting to login prompt.

Do you think there is something wrong with this pi zero 2W or perhaps my 3 chargers are not to spec for a zero 2W?

Any configuration I should try before getting an "official" charger just for this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: do you believe that the boot messages are just for decoration?

Comment: Which boot messages? I haven't said anything about boot messages being for decoration.

Comment: you said `During boot I can see the init messages going by`,  but you said nothing about the measages

Comment: Oh I see. They're too quick to read them properly. No obvious error appears that I can read.

Comment: try to take some pictures with a camera, or a video

Answer (score 0):

Update: it boots with an official power brick.